# Loading Data in Sortkey Order and VACUUM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am loading a nightly snapshot of a table into Redshift.
I have added a column called "rundate" at the end of the table, which just represents when the data was pulled through my ETL process.  It is also the primary sortkey.

The tables every night just gets longer and longer, and there are 400+ columns in many of them.

Right now I am using FILLRECORD in conjunction with EMPTYASNULL in order to get NULLS into the table, and once the COPY command has finished, I use

```
update table set rundate = 'date' where rundate is NULL
```

in order to have the correct snapshot date.

I am wondering if it is still considered as "loading the data in sortkey order", where I will not need to vacuum.  Aside from this, no updates/deletes are done to any of the records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no.  An update will perform a delete/insert leaving your entire load each day as dead records requiring VACUUM.  I would recommend loading into an empty stage table instead and then inserting the data with the extra rundate column after staging.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I did try to explain a query to determine if a vaccum was required, but I couldn't figure it out -

    explain select max(rundate) from table;

or 

    explain select * from table where rundate = (select max(rundate) from table)

before and after a vaccum on the test table both did a full scan.   Is this not the best way to access the most recent data?

Comment: Additionally, is there any difference between "select * into table from stage_table;" and "insert into table(select * from stage_table);"?

Comment: select ... from table will perform a full scan regardless as there are no indexes.  The delete however will leave dead rows/blocks that will be have to be scanned resulting in longer query time